# How to Update a list item from one list to another list using SP Designer workflow

Tags: designer-workflow

I have two lists. List 1 is Parent ( project name, status etc) and list 2 is Child ( project name, status, etc). I have created a workflow using the Create Item when an item in List 1 is added it creates a new item in List 2 using list 1's information (project name, status). I would like to have a workflow update List 2 if any of the information in List 1 changes for example if the status changes from Open to Resolved. I tried creating a workflow using Update item but it is not working. Is it possible to update List 2 when List 1 is updated using workflows?
If anyone knows plz explain with example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its definitely possible.

Anuja's approach will work but it needs some change (no need to create lookup).

When you create item in list 2 save item id to list 2. (e.g. Create one column in list 2 named "list1itemid" and save list 1 item's id to that column when you create an item into list 2.

Now create another workflow on list 1 updated event(or you can use existing with some condition) and update list 2 item by matching item id and list1itemid value.

I use this approach in my SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, When you create item in list 2 keep a lookup column pointing to ID for list1. So when any changes are made to list 1, search for the item in List 2 with column values as List1_ID. **This approach will work if you have only 1 item in list2 corresponding to list1.**

Comment: Hi Anuja,I tried but it is not working ? Can u explain with simple example.